# How can I Group By a query result where a table is joined on itself?

Tags: t-sql

I have a mess of a report, that is build up in spaghetti coding, doing 100's of SQL request, and bogging down the clients. I'm in the process of re-writing it, but my SQL feels like a mess.

I feel like I'm missing a key operation ...

The report shows the number of invoice, the sum of them, grouped by invoice type and filter based on the current month, the previous month, and the cumulative sum of the current year, and the previous year.

for simplicity, let's say all invoice are worth 100$ and I have 10 invoice of each type per area (outside of December) in 2017 and 2018.

So if I get the report for December, I want something like this :

> ```
>  type  || description  || location || 2017-DEC || 2018-DEC || 2017-CUMUL  || 2018-CUMUL
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> type A || descr. 'a'   || town 1   ||    1     ||    3    ||    1100$     || 1300$
> type B || descr. 'b    || town 1   ||    2     ||    4    ||    1200$     || 1400$
> ```

Anyone can shed a light on what I'm doing wrong here ?  the coalesce feels like cleaning up the mess made by wrong use of full outer join ...

here is my query so far :

```
select a.type
, a.desc
, a.area
, sum(a.prec_InvoiceNumber)
, sum(a.InvoiceNumber)
, sum(a.yprec_amount)
, sum(a.ycurr_amount)
 from ( 
    SELECT coalesce(CURR.type,prec.type, yprec.type,YCurr.type) as type
    , coalesce(CURR.desc,prec.desc, yprec.desc,YCurr.desc) as desc
    , coalesce(CURR.area,prec.area, yprec.area,YCurr.area) as area
    , isnull(PREC.InvoiceNumber,0) as prec_InvoiceNumber
    , isnull(CURR.InvoiceNumber,0) as InvoiceNumber
    , isnull(YPREC.amount,0) as YPREC_amount
    , isnull(YCurr.amount,0) as YCurr_amount 
    from 
    (
        SELECT invoice.type 
        , invoiceType.desc
        , locationarea.desc as area
        , Count(INVOICE.IDNumber) as InvoiceNumber,
        , SUM(Invoice.amount) as amount
        FROM Invoice
        left join invoicteype on invoice.type = invoicetype.type
        left join locationarea on locationarea.Id = invoice.locationID
        Where Invoice.date between '2017-12-01' and '2017-12-31'
        and invoicetype.type in ('a','b')
        and locationarea.ID = 1
         group by Invoice.type, locationarea.desc, invoiceType.desc
    ) PREC
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT invoice.type 
        , invoiceType.desc
        , locationarea.desc as area
        , Count(INVOICE.IDNumber) as InvoiceNumber,
        , SUM(Invoice.amount) as amount
        FROM Invoice
        left join invoicteype on invoice.type = invoicetype.type
        left join locationarea on locationarea.Id = invoice.locationID
        Where Invoice.date between '2018-12-01' and '2018-12-31'
        and invoicetype.type in ('a','b')
        and locationarea.ID = 1
        group by Invoice.type, locationarea.desc, invoiceType.desc
    ) CURR ON PREC.type= CURR.type AND PREC.area= CURR.area AND PREC.desc= CURR.desc
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT invoice.type 
        , invoiceType.desc
        , locationarea.desc as area
        , Count(INVOICE.IDNumber) as InvoiceNumber,
        , SUM(Invoice.amount) as amount
        FROM Invoice
        left join invoicteype on invoice.type = invoicetype.type
        left join locationarea on locationarea.Id = invoice.locationID
        Where Invoice.date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
        and invoicetype.type in ('a','b')
        and locationarea.ID = 1
        group by Invoice.type, locationarea.desc, invoiceType.desc
    ) YPREC ON CURR.type= YPREC.type AND CURR.area= YPREC.area AND CURR.desc= YPREC.desc
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT invoice.type 
        , invoiceType.desc
        , locationarea.desc as area
        , Count(INVOICE.IDNumber) as InvoiceNumber,
        , SUM(Invoice.amount) as amount
        FROM Invoice
        left join invoicteype on invoice.type = invoicetype.type
        left join locationarea on locationarea.Id = invoice.locationID
        Where Invoice.date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
        and invoicetype.type in ('a','b')
        and locationarea.ID = 1
        group by Invoice.type, locationarea.desc, invoiceType.desc
    ) YCURR ON CURR.type= YCURR .type AND CURR.area= YCURR.area AND CURR.desc= YCURR.desc
) a 
group by a.type, a.desc, a.area
```

**EDIT :**

I would be happy to get rid of the last 'select' and all the coalesce, I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it.

Since the way I created the full outer join, they all join up on the 1st sub query ('PREC'), so if an invoice type exists in 2018, but not in 2017, I have some messed up result ('hence' the clunky use of coalesce and the 'select a.' around the main 'select' and the full outer join subqueries )

in my head there should be a simpler way to write it along the line of :

```
select type, descr, location, count(a.id), count(b.Id), sum(c.value), sum(d.value) 
from TypeTable 
join locationtable  
join descriptiontable
join invoice a 
join invoice b
join invoice c
join invoice d 
where a.date between U and V 
and b.date between W and X
and c.date between U and Y
and d.date between W and z
and type = 'a' 
and description = 'descr a' 
and location = 'town 1'
```

without needing to add all those coalesce and sub-queries, but I can't find the way to do it.

Comment: It might help to show an example of the output you are getting that's wrong too.

Comment: the output isnt bad ... but that query is over simplified ... I have 7 or 8 table joined to get all of the data imput for a single invoice ( imagine you want that report by item on the invoice, and regroup by item part of a specific group(1 row for pencils, 1 for paper, etc )) ... so the whole query takes 100's of more lines ... i just wish I had a clean example to start working with.

each added joined table is include at least 4 more times, each with specific conditions, which makes the number of resulting parameters kinda hard to follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the main difference you are dealing with in the different join sub-queries is the date range if I understand correctly. In order to be able to merge results from a single date range even if the specific dates are different, you could try using a `CASE` expression to return the same values for all rows within the same date range. For example, you could use a `CASE` expression to return the beginning of the date range for any date within the range. Or if you don't care about the actual date value, but just want to sort it into separate groups, assign any number.

```
SELECT a.description, invoice_sum
FROM (
SELECT description, sum(a.InvoiceNumber) invoice_sum,
       CASE WHEN date between U and V then 1
            WHEN date between W and X then 2
            WHEN date between U and Y then 3
            WHEN date between W and Z then 4
       ELSE 5 END dategroup
FROM Invoice
) a
GROUP BY a.dategroup, a.description
```

Comment: Yeah, the date range is the only different parameters. I'm not sure how using a case to get a specific value will help me, can you show a simple exemple (english isnt my main language ) ?

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier Does that help?

Comment: wait, scratch that ... I guess I could make a between U and V and not between W and Z, and just add the 2 sum for the cumul ... I'll go try it out.

Comment: Alright, it worked out nicely. seems alot cleaner now too, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this...
DECLARE @monthtoview  int
SET @monthtoview=12
;WITH acummyear AS (
 SELECT invoice.type

```
    , locationID as area
   -- , INVOICE.IDNumber as InvoiceNumber
    ,year( dbo.Invoice.[date]) AS [year]
    ,month( dbo.Invoice.[date]) AS [month]
    , SUM(Invoice.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.Invoice.type, year( dbo.Invoice.[date]) ) as amountyear
    ,Invoice.amount AS amountmonth
    FROM Invoice

    Where Invoice.date> '2016-12-31' and Invoice.date<= '2018-12-31' -- years 2017 and 2018
    AND locationID = 1
    AND type IN (1,2)
    )

SELECT type,a.area,a.[year],a.[month]
,count(a.type) as invoicecount
,max(a.amountyear) AS amountperyear
,sum(a.amountmonth) AS amountpermonth
 from  acummyear a --join here your type and location tables
 WHERE a.[month]=@monthtoview 
  GROUP BY type,a.area,a.[year],a.[month]
```

but in your report(ssrs) use a matrix to display the values, your rows will be the type and location and your columns... one for year(20XX-CUMUL)with amountperyear in the value and another one for year/month(20XX-DEC)with invoicecount in the value, remove the "sum" added to the values in the cell.

Comment: If not using this framework of mine and being purely in sql, this would most likely have worked. I need to work more with CTE and learnt them for good. 

I've given my answer to the guy who answered me 1st though, thanks for the nice example.